# Google App Script: Sharing and publishing different versions of the script across different domain accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, version, share, publish

How do you share a Google App Script across several different domain accounts? (note: these are separate customers with their own domain accounts)

Only the script owner can publish a script, therefore sharing the source script requires the respective domain admin user to make a copy of the script.  This of-course generates a different script ID.

Opening this copy-of-the-script means that I have no other managed versions of the script.  If I create a new "Managed Version" and follow the instructions for provisioning the Add-On I end up with a separate publishing project, with separate OAuth credentials, etc.

This results in new clientId+clientSecret for each released version of the script.  The "Managed Versions" option only seems to handle edits of the script from within the domain account the script copy resides.

How can I manage version control of my app script when I'm forced to create [a new app script + publish project + OAuth credentials] every time I need to make a change to the code?    This way, every publishing project has just one managed version of the app script.

How does everyone else manage code changes across entirely separate domain accounts?

Answer (score 0):

[Publish your script as an Add-on for Domain-Wide Installation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide) Admins across different domains will then be able to install your application while you maintain a single code-base.

Comment: The article above refers to deploying to a single domain.  As the developer, I have the code deployed to my domain, where I can manage version control of the released script.  What I can't find is an article that details how I can distribute the script to other domains.

Note: These "other" domains are not owned by me.  They are customers who already have google domain accounts setup that I would be publishing my private domain app script to

Comment: Maybe private domain apps cannot be distributed across "other" domains in this way?  Maybe I need a publicly available app?